# Android SignalA, parameters value in Invoke method

Tags: android, signalr

I am using SignalA android library.
I was able to communicate with server successfully, but had a problem with parameters.
In Android I use Collection to store parameters:

```
Collection<String> sendMessageContent = new HashSet<String>();    
sendMessageContent.add(receiver_name);
                sendMessageContent.add(message);
                sendMessageContent.add(Long.toString(product));
                hub.Invoke("SendChatMessage", sendMessageContent, new HubInvokeCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void OnResult(boolean b, String s) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "success to send message!" + b + s );
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void OnError(Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                });
```

On server side I have this method:

```
public void SendChatMessage(string receiver_name, string message, long product_id)
    { //skip implementation }
```

I am able to receive value of parameters on server, but the value of receiver_name is value of message, and value of message is receiver_name. If I add message first to Collection then add receiver_name, I get the correct value for both. Can anyone give me idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If I use List instead of Collection, it works as expected.